# How to get to the next Waterfallstep after Choice Prompt?

Tags: c#, botframework

In the first step of this Dialog, I want to ask the user what they want to do with a Choice prompt. After the return, where I would expect the dialog to go to the next Waterfallstep (HandleChoiceAsync), it instead returns to it's parentdialog.

I seem to remember this used to work before. Thanks in advance!

[MainDialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2rwc.png)

[OrdersDialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a53TN.png)

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> AskForProductsAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        productList = (List<Product>)stepContext.Options;  

        if(productList.Count > 0)
        {
            string producten = "";

            foreach(Product p in productList)
            {
                producten += p.GetProductName() + ", ";
            }
            producten = producten.Remove(producten.Length - 2);
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync("In je bestelling staan nu de volgende producten: " + producten + ".");
        }

        //choice prompt does not go to next waterfallstep, instead returns to parent dialog
        return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ChoicePrompt), new PromptOptions
        {
            Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Wil je nog een product toevoegen of verwijderen?"),
            RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Probeer het nog een keer"),
            Choices = ChoiceFactory.ToChoices(new List<string> { "Toevoegen", "Verwijderen", "Klaar met bestellen" })
        }, cancellationToken);
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> HandleChoiceAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        FoundChoice choice = (FoundChoice)stepContext.Result;
        switch (choice.Index)
        {
            case 0:
                toevoegen = true;
                var messageText = "Welk product wil je toevoegen?";
                var promptMessage = MessageFactory.Text(messageText, messageText, InputHints.ExpectingInput);
                return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = promptMessage }, cancellationToken);
            case 1:
                toevoegen = false;
                List<string> productsString = new List<string>();
                foreach (Product p in productList)
                {
                    productsString.Add(p.GetProductName());
                }
                return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ChoicePrompt), new PromptOptions
                {
                    Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Welk product wil je verwijderen?"),
                    Choices = ChoiceFactory.ToChoices(productsString)
                }, cancellationToken);
            case 2:
                return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(productList);
            default:
                break;

        }

        return await stepContext.NextAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Can you log the value of `choice` to console to see what's going on? Without something really weird going on, it seems you are ending up at case 2 where you are calling endDialog.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on HandleChoiceAsync just before the switch, check if it's being hit, then the choice value might be the issue and you are hitting case: 2 and ending the dialog

Comment: @MarcAsmar, I tried that, it doesn't even get to that point. When I put the breakpoint on the ' return await stepContext.PromptAsync' part, it skips back to the parent dialog after the AskForProductsAsync step.
Which is weird, because I do the exact same thing in another dialog and it works fine there.

Comment: @JuriaanTöning are you saving conversation state? If the conversation state is not being saved then it won't be able to continue where it left off

Comment: @MarcAsmar not specifically in the Dialogs, how would I use that?
It works perfectly fine with only MainDialog and the first childDialog, but when that childDialog also starts a dialog (The dialog shown above), this suddenly doesn't work anymore. Is that a conversationstate issue?

Comment: I have tested your code and it works fine for me, are you sure the same code with text prompt works? does it move to the next step?

Comment: @MarcAsmar When I run this code alone, it works. When I call this Dialog from MainDialog, it works.

When in MainDialog i call OrdersDialog, and from OrdersDialog i call this Dialog, it does not work

Comment: Show me how you are calling it from OrdersDialog, If OrdersDialog is a waterfall dialog and you are calling this dialog from a step inside of orders, the step will not wait and will continue to the next step unless you: return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(...);

Comment: @MarcAsmar I've added the images in the main post above, one from the MainDialog where I call OrdersDialog, and one from te OrdersDialog where I call the AddProductsToOrderDialog

Comment: When AskForProductsAsync hits, instead of going to the next step in that dialog, you are being sent back to the next step in OrdersDialog ? ( are there many steps in OrdersDialog  ? )

Comment: @MarcAsmar Exactly, but it returns to OrdersDialog where it left off (in step 1 of 5). Then it immediately returns to MainDialog as well...

Looks almost like BeginDialogAsync(); only starts the first step of the waterfallDialog. Strange that this happens with this construction, but not when I remove one of the Dialogs and only use OrderDialog or AddProductsToOrderDialog (and not both)

Comment: This is happening because, when you are inside of a waterfall step, unless you return a prompt it will not wait and it will continue going to the next step, so when you begin that new dialog the parent one being a waterfall dialog itself, will continue to the next step even though you started another dialog

Comment: Thanks for your time and investigation, I'll try a different solution in that case